# helm CLI incorrectly splits on commas

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

When using the helm command and overriding values using --set, if the key value contains a comma, the value is halted there. i want to pass a value with comma.

For example `-set connString=service_name:8080,password=xxxxx=,abortConnect=False`

and in my helm I'm using this connection string.

```
connString: ""

Cons__cache: "{{ .Values.connString}}"
```

But service_name:8080 is stored.

Comment: If you can write out a YAML (or JSON) file with the values and pass that with `helm install -f`, that has a much more consistent syntax than `helm install --set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
--set connString='service_name:8080\,password=xxxxx=\,abortConnect=False'
```

or

```
--set connString=service_name:8080\,password=xxxxx=\,abortConnect=False
```

Link references:
[image]
https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/
https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1556